# WonderMedia 8650 ICS 4.0.3 - what is "3g_server"

Tags: usb-modem

I'm trying to understand how a WM-8650 based Android tablet running ICS 4.0.3 manages its 3G connection using a USB modem.

I've used OpenWRT-based linux routers in the past, and these use usb_modeswitch to kick the modem out of "CD" mode into "modem" mode, and then pppd starts up and uses chat to set up the connection, though I've never quite got to the bottom of how the USB hotplug system kicks things off when the dongle is first plugged in.

With Android I can see similar things happening - usb_modeswitch kicks the dongle into the right mode, and a renamed pppd (called ppp3g) sets of the point-to-point protocol.  However, this is all done under the control of a process called "3g_server" which I've been unable to find any information on.

I'm trying to debug a problem where a dropped connection fails to come back up very quickly, so I'd like to understand how 3g_server works and what options I have for tuning that behaviour.  A configuration document would be handy, source code would be better.

I tried going to http://www.wondermedia.com.tw/en/support/ but, despite the "en" in the URL, the page is in Chinese.  Can anyone help?

Comment: You might want to go and ask this similar question over on Stack Overflow. It seems to be a lot more about the code than the actual use of Android.

Comment: Fair point - was considering putting it on SO in the first place but wasn't sure where to draw the line with Android "enthusiasm".  I've flagged it for moderator attention.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a developer question to me, though it's certainly on the very advanced end of what we do here.  You might not get a good answer.

Comment: I also think that this question is fine here. It's not a development questions but more a curious user question :)

Comment: It is more "developer" than "enthusiastic user" so I've reposted to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17387897/wondermedia-8650-ics-4-0-3-what-is-3g-server